# Moving to previous query in XSB or Ciao (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

While using swi-prolog, one can recall previous query using the UP arrow key (at the terminal). How can this be achieved in XSB or Ciao prolog systems?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55144088/772868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend using [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs), running a shell in an emacs buffer (with a "dumb" terminal).

That way I can use META-P (Alt-P) to suggest previous commands.

Running a shell in emacs has many other advantages: find/replace, save to disk, to name a few.