# up,down,left and right cannot be used when using SWI-Prolog in terminal

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I met a problem when I use prolog(swipl), after I type swipl in the terminal, code like '^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C' shows when I press up, down, left, and right on my keyboard. 
Could somebody explain why? and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Someone told me to enter 'bash' in the terminal before I enter 'swipl', but it's not working actually...

Comment: This means the readline/editline functionality isn't working. If you built it yourself, you probably have to install the development version of one of those libraries first and then rebuild. Or you can install `rlwrap` and do `rlwrap swipl` (which is helpful for other commands as well).

Comment: I tried it just now, it really worked, thank you!@DanielLyons

Comment: @DanielLyons: your comment should be **the** answer... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means the readline/editline functionality isn't working. If you built it yourself, you probably have to install the development version of one of those libraries first and then rebuild. Or you can install `rlwrap` and do `rlwrap swipl` (which is helpful for other commands as well).